# ConstraintLayout doesn't match parent completely

Tags: android, xml, data-binding

I have a ScrollView that wraps a ConstraintLayout, the issue is that despite the ScrollView does match completely the screen, the Constraint doesn't. I have settled both to match_parent, but the ConstraintLayout doesn't fill around a 20% on the bottom as you can see in the image, the blue line of the bottom is the max height of my ConstraintLayout [image], I have read many articles but haven't been able to find an answer, I don't know if this is related to data-binding. Here my code `

```
<data>
    <variable
        name="bindingViewModel"
        type="com.example.workoutstopwatch.MainActivityViewModel" />
</data>

<androidx.core.widget.NestedScrollView
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">

    <androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent">

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/textView3"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginStart="10sp"
            android:layout_marginLeft="10sp"
            android:layout_marginTop="10sp"
            android:layout_marginEnd="10dp"
            android:layout_marginRight="10dp"
            android:text="@string/set_your_work_out_time"
            android:textSize="30sp"
            app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" />

        <EditText
            android:id="@+id/edit_work_text"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
            android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
            android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
            android:layout_marginStart="10dp"
            android:layout_marginLeft="10dp"
            android:layout_marginTop="8dp"
            android:layout_weight="3"
            android:hint="@string/_00"
            android:inputType="number"
            android:maxLength="2"
            android:text="@={bindingViewModel.workOutTime}"
            android:textSize="80sp"
            app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/textView3" />

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/up_arrow_work"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
            android:layout_alignParentEnd="true"
            android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
            android:layout_gravity="top"
            android:layout_marginStart="180dp"
            android:layout_marginLeft="180dp"
            android:layout_marginTop="4dp"
            android:layout_marginEnd="50dp"
            android:layout_marginRight="50dp"
            android:background="@drawable/arrow_left_foreground"
            android:onClick="setDurationType"
            android:rotation="90"
            app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="1.0"
            app:layout_constraintStart_toEndOf="@+id/edit_work_text"
            app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/textView3" />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/work_min_or_secs_text"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_alignBottom="@+id/up_arrow_work"
            android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
            android:layout_alignParentEnd="true"
            android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
            android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
            android:layout_marginTop="52dp"
            android:hint="Secs"
            android:text="@{bindingViewModel.workMinOrSecsText}"
            android:textSize="30sp"
            app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="@+id/down_arrow_work"
            app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.739"
            app:layout_constraintStart_toEndOf="@+id/edit_work_text"
            app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/textView3"
            app:layout_constraintVertical_bias="0.0" />

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/down_arrow_work"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_alignParentEnd="true"
            android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
            android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
            android:layout_gravity="top"
            android:layout_marginStart="180dp"
            android:layout_marginLeft="180dp"
            android:layout_marginTop="40dp"
            android:layout_marginEnd="50dp"
            android:layout_marginRight="50dp"
            android:background="@drawable/arrow_left_foreground"
            android:onClick="setDurationType"
            android:rotation="90"
            android:rotationX="189"
            app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.983"
            app:layout_constraintStart_toEndOf="@+id/edit_work_text"
            app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/up_arrow_work" />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/textView4"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginStart="10dp"
            android:layout_marginLeft="10dp"
            android:layout_marginTop="197dp"
            android:layout_marginEnd="10dp"
            android:layout_marginRight="10dp"
            android:layout_marginBottom="163dp"
            android:text="@string/set_your_rest_time"
            android:textSize="30sp"
            app:layout_constraintBottom_toTopOf="@+id/textView5"
            app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.304"
            app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" />

        <EditText
            android:id="@+id/edit_rest_text"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
            android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
            android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
            android:layout_marginStart="10dp"
            android:layout_marginLeft="10dp"
            android:layout_marginTop="12dp"
            android:layout_weight="3"
            android:hint="@string/_00"
            android:inputType="number"
            android:maxLength="2"
            android:text="@={bindingViewModel.restTime}"
            android:textSize="80sp"
            app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/textView4" />


        <Button
            android:id="@+id/up_arrow_rest"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
            android:layout_alignParentEnd="true"
            android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
            android:layout_gravity="top"
            android:layout_marginStart="180dp"
            android:layout_marginLeft="180dp"
            android:layout_marginTop="4dp"
            android:layout_marginEnd="50dp"
            android:layout_marginRight="50dp"
            android:background="@drawable/arrow_left_foreground"
            android:onClick="setDurationType"
            android:rotation="90"
            app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="1.0"
            app:layout_constraintStart_toEndOf="@+id/edit_rest_text"
            app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/textView4" />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/rest_min_or_secs_text"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_alignBottom="@+id/up_arrow_work"
            android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
            android:layout_alignParentEnd="true"
            android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
            android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
            android:layout_marginTop="52dp"
            android:hint="Secs"
            android:text="@{bindingViewModel.restMinOrSecsText}"
            android:textSize="30sp"
            app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="@+id/down_arrow_rest"
            app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.739"
            app:layout_constraintStart_toEndOf="@+id/edit_rest_text"
            app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/textView4"
            app:layout_constraintVertical_bias="0.0" />

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/down_arrow_rest"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_alignParentEnd="true"
            android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
            android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
            android:layout_gravity="top"
            android:layout_marginStart="180dp"
            android:layout_marginLeft="180dp"
            android:layout_marginTop="40dp"
            android:layout_marginEnd="50dp"
            android:layout_marginRight="50dp"
            android:background="@drawable/arrow_left_foreground"
            android:onClick="setDurationType"
            android:rotation="90"
            android:rotationX="189"
            app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.983"
            app:layout_constraintStart_toEndOf="@+id/edit_rest_text"
            app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/up_arrow_rest" />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/textView5"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginStart="10dp"
            android:layout_marginLeft="10dp"
            android:layout_marginEnd="10dp"
            android:layout_marginRight="10dp"
            android:layout_marginBottom="168dp"
            android:text="@string/set_your_number_of_reps"
            android:textSize="30sp"
            app:layout_constraintBottom_toTopOf="@+id/start_text"
            app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.611"
            app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/textView4" />

        <EditText
            android:id="@+id/edit_reps_text"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
            android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
            android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
            android:layout_marginStart="10dp"
            android:layout_marginLeft="10dp"
            android:layout_marginTop="16dp"
            android:layout_weight="3"
            android:hint="@string/_00"
            android:inputType="number"
            android:maxLength="2"
            android:text="@={bindingViewModel.numberOfReps}"
            android:textSize="80sp"
            app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/textView5" />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/start_text"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
            android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
            android:layout_alignParentEnd="true"
            android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
            android:gravity="center"
            android:onClick="startTraining"
            android:text="START!"
            android:textColor="#FF1800"
            android:textSize="60sp"
            app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent" />

    </androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>
</androidx.core.widget.NestedScrollView>
```

`

Comment: Have you tried running this ? My IDE is showing full sized layout, looking as you described it

Comment: Yes off course,  did you tried it with data-binding?

Comment: @Yop you should know that scroll view should have only a direct child. The child should know that its height `wrap_content`